# python assignment fails in else part of conditional operation

Tags: python

Why assignment fails at else part ? I was trying to increment two variables based on a condition in below one line .

```
>>> a=0
>>> b=0
>>> a+=1 if True else b
>>> a
>>> 1
>>> a if True else b+=1
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
>>> a if False else b+=1
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
>>> a+=1 if False else b
>>> a
>>> 1
>>> a+=1 if True else b+=1
  File "<input>", line 1
    a+=1 if True else b+=1
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The syntax is `expression if condition else expression` — `b+=1` is not an expression.

Comment: @khelwood: Yes, but i wondered why it worked `a+=1 if False else b`. But the accepted answer from @liliscent clarified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a+=1 if True else b` is parsed as

```
a += (1 if True else b)
```

In Python, assignment is **not** an expression.

Comment: Thanks  for the clarification,  Just confused when `a+=1` worked at `if` part. But actually worked because of parsing as you explained.

Answer (score 4):

In python, in a single line, the right side of assignment operator you can't use assignment again.

for example `a = b + (c = d)`, cannot be done in python.

Referring to above example again:

### Valid operations

```
b = 10
a = 20

a+=1 if True else b  # this is valid.
a+=1 if False else b  # this is valid.
```

### Invalid operations

```
a if True else b+=1  # this is invalid.
a if False else b+=1  # this is invalid.
a+=1 if True else b+=1  # this is invalid.
t = a if True else b=1  # this is invalid.
```

In these statements, if we try to print 
`a if True else b` would have printed b value.
But above code, trying to use assignment in the expression, it will not be allowed in python.

This kind of syntax is allowed in C language, but not in python.
For example, in C-language we can write like

```
if (a=10): printf("%d", a);
```

Will actually does assignment inside the condition to a and pass the condition and executes if part.

In python, it just throws an error if you write code as:

```
if a=10: print a
```

one can only write in python like

```
if a==10 : print a
```

Comment: Thanks ! The problem was when I read the line `a+=1 if True else b`  as a ternary like if else instead of assignment statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
if True: a+=1
else: b+=1
```

Comment: Yes, I could. But i was trying to write in one line.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is the meaning of the syntax `x if cond else y` in python.  What this syntax mean is not `operation_a if condition else operation_b` but rather `value_a if condition else value_b`

This means the correct way of using it is

```
var = val1 if condition else val2
```

And not:

```
var1=val1 if condition else var2=val2
```

Read more at:[details about if else oneliner operator](https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/)

P.S: using a hack like:

```
(var1=val1)  if condition else (var2=val2)
```

Might work,  but don't use it since it is not pythonic and the return value of this statement is not obvious at first glance ("explicit is better then implicit")